# Rearrange Fields in Python

Tags: python, file, csv, dictionary

I am trying to make my python program display the name of the employee, salary, and department in a list. Here is my csv file:

```
Name, Salary, Department
Pika Chu, 5000, Pokemon
Peter Parker, 10000, Friendly Neighborhood Spiderman
Bruce Lee, 25000, Kung Fu Master
Trevor Phillips, 30000, Grand Theft Auto
Willy Wonka, 1000000, Chocolatier
Mario, 84000, Plumber
Sonic, 20000, Runner
```

And here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import csv
import os



def read_employees(file):


 open(file, 'r')


 csv.register_dialect('stfDialect', skipinitialspace=True, strict=True)
 staffFile = csv.DictReader(open(file), dialect = 'stfDialect')

 staffList = []
 for data in staffFile:
     staffList.append(data)
 return staffList

staffList = read_employees("Staff.csv")
print(staffList)
```

The output is this:

```
{'Name': 'Pika Chu', 'Salary': '5000', 'Department': 'Pokemon'}
```

But I want the output to display the data like this:

```
{'Department': 'Pokemon', 'Salary': '5000', 'Name': 'Pika Chu'}
```

May I know how I can make this happen?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import os
def read_employees(file):
  csv.register_dialect('stfDialect', skipinitialspace=True, strict=True)
  with open(file, r') as f
    staffFile = csv.DictReader(f, dialect = 'stfDialect')
  return list(staffFile)

staffList = read_employees("Staff.csv")
for e in staffList:
  print({k: e[k] for k in ('Department', 'Salary', 'Name')})
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using python 3.

Comment: Python 3.6 is a version of Python 3. This is the solution you want if you can use 3.6 or later. Earlier versions you use the slower and more complicated OrderedDict.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I get this error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: Well, that was only the `print` part. Now I show the whole code (with some improvements over your original).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OrderedDict`:

```
 from collections import OrderedDict

 staffList = []
 fields_order = ["Department", "Salary", "Name"]
 for data in staffFile:
     o_d = OrderedDict()
     for field in fields_order:
        o_d[field] = data["field"]
     staffList.append(o_d)
 return staffList
```